# params[:page] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

I have the following code

```
# Gemfile

gem 'will_paginate'


# /config/initializers/will_paginate_array.rb

require 'will_paginate/collection'

Array.class_eval do
  def paginate(page = 1, per_page = 15)
    WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, size) do |pager|
      pager.replace self[pager.offset, pager.per_page].to_a
    end
  end
end


# /app/controllers/games_controller.rb

def show
  @presenter = GamesPresenter.new(json)
  @games = @presenter.games.paginate(params[:page], 5)
end


# /app/views/games/index.html.erb

<% @games.each do |game| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @games %>
```

however when i try to pass params[:page] at `line @games = @presenter.games.paginate(params[:page], 5)`  i get `params[:page]`  to be nil. Does anybody know why this could be the case? . If add page=1 if page.blank? only gives me the first page results ..Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 3):

`params[:page]` by default is `nil`.  I suggest you to handle this scenario by changing your class_eval to

```
def paginate(page = 1, per_page = 15)
  page ||= 1
  WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, size) do |pager|
    pager.replace self[pager.offset, pager.per_page].to_a
  end
end
```

when you pass `nil` as the first parameter, it will not use `1` because you explicitly passed a value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ...but again it just gives me the 1st set of results and changing the page just splits those results. {for example in my case i am just getting the 1st 100 results and the rest aren't coming}. Would you know why ?

Comment: may i ask what you're trying to achieve? are you trying to paginate arrays (based on the filename of the initializer file)

Comment: yeah the same ... So i don't know why i get only the first 100 results through a search ...but without will_paginate i get more ..

Comment: will_paginate can paginate array. just add `require 'will_paginate/array'` in an initializer file. it accepts a hash for `page` and `per_page` options

Comment: yeah i know that is what i am passing in ...The thing is that when i just use limit and offset to be 100 and don't use will paginate i get more results but now i just get the 1st 100 results ... and not the next 100 and so on...

Comment: did you find the solution to this?